# Delete single raster from Raster Dataset

Tags: raster, arcgis-desktop, data

Is there any possibility to delete single raster previously loaded to a Raster Dataset?

Comment: @ novicegis..are you using Java or .NET?

Comment: I use .NET 4.0, arcobjects 10.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A raster dataset is a simple image type.  It has pixel type, bands, and an extent (among other properties). When you "add" a raster to a raster dataset, you're really mosaicking into the previous image (by comparison, a "mosaic dataset" or a "raster catalog" are collections of discrete rasters, possibly overlapping, with rules to determine how the synthesis of the raster is returned).

If you add two neighboring DTED tiles of size 1201x1201 pixels, you create a 1201x2401 (or 2401x1201) raster.  Even if you could "delete" the added pixels, what you'd really accomplish is populating 1201x1201 NODATA values in that 1201x2401 image (losing the shared pixel values at the edge).  If something goes wrong, and you add a distant tile, then you'd have a very large raster -- one which is mostly NODATA, and erasing the incorrect data isn't the same as using a backup snapshot of the state of the raster dataset before its extent was corrupted.

If, however, you have a large mosiac and paste incorrect data into the middle of the raster, you could probably "patch" the raster dataset by reloading the valid values over the top of the corrupted pixels.  This is the only general case where you could "delete" an incorrectly added tile from a raster dataset.

Comment: Great, thank you Vince for your advice! So, as far as I understand, I can replace 'wrong' raster with new, correct one with the same name - am I write?

Comment: Yes, you can certainly drop the incorrect raster dataset and create a new one with the correct data.

Comment: Check out the cropping tools under Windows->Image Analysis in ArcEditor.  You can use the Crop and Mask to help with this patching process.  After you are satisfied with your edits, you can export the resulting function raster layer into a new raster dataset.